# How can i add external js libraries in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

How can i add an external js library into create react app project ?
i tried everything but nothing worked.
here is what i assume should work :
i add these into the head of the index.html :

```
  <script src="lib/superfish/superfish.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/modal-video/js/modal-video.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the error i get:

-Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

-Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
    at HTMLDocument. ((index):65)

Comment: Usually you'd add the required libraries as dependencies in your package.json and use `require()` to import them. Given the error message you are getting, it looks like you have a syntax error unrelated to the code you've posted.

Comment: Yeah, I would re create your create-react-app if you don't spot the problem. @ChrisPickford is right.

Comment: @ChrisPickford yeah i think that it's because of some comments in the source files, can you please tell me exactly how to add them in my package.json and then later use require ? ( i'm kinda of a new programmer)

Comment: Most likely the problem is with the location of these dependencies. Please check the network tab of devtools if it was the case. Otherwise, the order of scripts can be a problem.

Comment: the first error is because of something i can't really figure out in the js libraries " jquery-migrate.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "  @Aditya

Comment: @AlejandroGarciaAnglada I'd suggest creating the example react application from the getting started tutorial. This should teach you everything you need to know.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I made several create-react-app projects before and i used react-router and even uploaded them to a server, so i'm kinda sure that i my create-react-app project itself is correct , what i do not know however is how to add an external js library

Comment: @ChrisPickford i would really really appreciate your help if you could explain how to implement what you said in your first comment about the json and the require